# Is there Slice()'s negative function?

Tags: javascript, slice

As you know, slice() returns the sliced item. For example, **"hello".slice(1, 3)** returns "ell", not the remainder. What I'm curious is this : Is there any function or way to get the remainder of slice()?

Comment: `.slice(3)` will return the substring that follows `.slice(n, 3)`?

Comment: Nope, you must manually concatenate `'hello'.slice(0, 1) + 'hello'.slice(3)`

Comment: It's a oneliner: `const removeSection = (string, from=0, to=string.length) => string.slice(0, from) + string.slice(to);` usage: `removeSection('hello', 1, 3)`

Comment: Any cleaner and simple way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
 String.prototype.remainderOfSlice = function(begin, end) {

    begin = begin || 0
    end = (end === undefined) ? this.length : end 

    if (this.slice(begin, end) === '') return this + ''
    return this.slice(0, begin) + this.slice(end) 
 }



console.log("hello".slice()) // "hello"
console.log("hello".remainderOfSlice()) // ""

console.log("hello".slice(-3)) // "llo"
console.log("hello".remainderOfSlice(-3)) // "he"

console.log("hello".slice(-3, 0)) // ""
console.log("hello".remainderOfSlice(-3, 0)) // "hello"

console.log("hello".slice(1, 3)) // "el"
console.log("hello".remainderOfSlice(1, 3)) // "hlo"
```

Comment: But How about splitting the front part and the back part into a 2-element array?